# 401 UNAUTHORIZED From Flask RESTAPI

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am attempting to log a user in and retrieve an auth token for the user; however, I am getting a 401 UNAUTHORIZED.  Researching this issue I keep coming across the "Authorization Header" is incorrect or invalid; however, I am logging the user in and I do not have a valid auth code yet.  I cannot understand why CORS will not allow this request through:

Using AXIOS:

```
export const sendServer = (url, token, method, data, callback) => {
    let newUrl = `http://localhost:5000/${url}`
    axios({
        method: method.toUpperCase(),
        url: newUrl,
        data: data,
        headers: { 'Authorization': token }
    })
    .then(response => callback({ success: true, data: response.data }))
    .catch(error => callback({ success: false, error: error.toJSON() }))
}
```

On The Flask side:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from config import ProdConfig
from auth import Authenticate, check_token

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(ProdConfig)
CORS(app)

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Authenticate, '/login', endpoint="login")
```

The '/login' endpoint does not require authentication.

```
class Authenticate(Resource):       
    def __init__(self):
        self.pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],default="pbkdf2_sha256",pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=30000)
                     
    def post(self):                
        if request.endpoint == 'login':      
        .......
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.